# xcodebuild --exportLocalization produces invalid content when used with SwiftUI Text(NSLocalizedString("key", value:"value")

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I'm running into an issue when exporting strings to an xliff file with xcode (14.2)

my code looks like this:

```
Text(NSLocalizedString("[feature] string key", value: "string value", comment: "string comment"))
```

When I export localizations (either though xcode ui or with `xcodebuild --exportLocalizations` I get a warning like this:

```
WARNING: Key "[feature] string key" used with multiple values. Value "[feature] string key" kept. Value "string value" ignored
```

and indeed the xliff file contains the equivalent content:

```
<trans-unit ... id="[feature] string key" ...>
  <source>[feature] string key</source>
  <target>[feature] string key</target>
  <note>string comment</note>
</trans-unit>
```

The issue goes away when the code is adjusted to store `NSLocalizedString` in a variable, sorta like this:

```
let x = NSLocalizedString("[feature] string key", value: "string value", comment: "string comment")
Text(x)
```

Having that workaround is ok (and other workarounds might also exist), but it's pretty easy to mistakenly use the invalid pattern, and I'd like to understand why this would be happening in the first place and if there's a way to fix it. The project has been using `Text(NSLocalizedString(...)` to some extent, it never differentiated between a string keys and their english values (which is what [apple recommends afaik](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1418095-nslocalizedstring/#3782935))

I have little iOS/apple ecosystem developer experience and my only hypothesis is that the offending code is interpreted as something like this during extraction:

```
NSLocalizedString("[feature] string key", value: "string value", comment: "string comment")
Text("[feature] string key")
```

The latter being then "folded" into a string which key and value are both equal to "[feature] string key", but don't know a way to see through the opaqueness of the localization export process.

Some guides (namely: [how-to-localize-swiftui](https://www.ibabbleon.com/copywriter-translator/2021/01/how-to-localize-swiftui-elements-in-xcode-12-nslocalizedstring/) and [swiftui localization tutorial](https://www.ibabbleon.com/swiftui_localization_tutorial.html#nslocalizedstring) recommend the exact pattern that's not working for me.

Out of notable build settings the project I'm encountering this is using [SWIFT_EMIT_LOC_STRINGS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/build-settings-reference#Use-Compiler-to-Extract-Swift-Strings) is set to NO, whille [LOCALIZED_STRING_SWIFTUI_SUPPORT](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/build-settings-reference#Localized-String-SwiftUI-Support) is set to YES.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this as well. I noticed that if I pull my `NSLocalizedString` into a variable it works as expected.

```swift
var body: some View {
    Text(x)
}

var x: String {
    NSLocalizedString("some.random.key", value: "An English String", comment: "A test string!")
}
```